# jQuery Require Text Field when Dropdown is Certain Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin to validate a form. I have a dropdown select with about 20 choices. If someone chooses only certain ones I need the Comments field right bellow it to become required so that they put in an explanation. I am using the following code for the rule but it will not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    'comments': {
            required: {
            depends: function(element){
                if ($('#description').val() == 'Company Jobs' || $('#description').val() == 'Engineering Administration' || $('#description').val() == 'Customer Service') {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
                minlength: 20

                        }
```

All other validation rules work in the form, even the minlength for the Comments field itself. But if I choose one of the listed values the field will not become required.

Tried this as well:

```
    'comments': {
        required: {
        depends: function(element){
            if ($('#description option:selected').text() == 'Company Jobs') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
            minlength: 20

                    }
```

Does not work.

Comment: I tried this as well: ` 'comments': {required: function(element){return $("#description option:selected").text() == "Company Jobs";},minlength: 20` Does not work as well.

Comment: Please do not dump code into comments.  Just click the `edit` link and edit your question.  Thanks.

Comment: *"Does not work"* is not a helpful description of the problem.  Also would be good if you could include the relevant HTML markup so we don't have to guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is working perfectly fine for me, so you must have some problem elsewhere that you haven't shown us.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#demo').validate({
        rules: {
            description: {
                required: true
            },
            comments: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        if ($('#description option:selected').text() == 'Company Jobs') {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // form demo
            alert('valid form');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

HTML markup:

```
<form id="demo">
    <select name="description" id="description">
        <option value="">please select...</option>
        <option value="CompanyJobs">Company Jobs</option>
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="comments" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/h7fz3cx5/**

You could also just use one line here...

```
comments: {
    required: {
        depends: function(element) {
            return ($('#description option:selected').text() == 'Company Jobs');
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tgd75n3k/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for the select:

HTML

```
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <select class="js-select2 form-control" id="description" name="description" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Start typing to choose a description...">
                                <option></option><!-- Required for data-placeholder attribute to work with Select2 plugin -->
                                <?php

                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                echo "<option value='" . $row['description'] . "'>" . $row['description'] . "</option>";} ?>
                                </select>
                        </div>
```

Rules & Messages for validation:

```
      rules: {
            'date': {
                required: true

            },
            'description': {
                required: true

            },

            'rt': {
                required: true,
                currency: ['$', false]

            },
            'ot': {
                required: true,
                currency: ['$', false]

            },

            'comments': {
        required: {
        depends: function(element){
            if ($('#description option:selected').text() == 'Company Jobs') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
            minlength: 20

                    }



        },
        messages: {
            'date': 'Please enter a valid date.',
            'description': 'Please choose a description.',
            'rt': 'Please enter a valid period of time.',
            'ot': 'Please enter a valid period of time.',
            'comments': {
                required: 'Please enter some comments.',
                minlength: 'You must have more to say than that! How about some more detail.'}

        }
```

As I said all the validation works great except for the comments field not becoming required. Minlength on it even works. Now thinking that it may be the fact that I am using the jQuery select2 plugin on the select field? Any thoughts?